# Show that for all $n ∈ Z$, $2n^3 + 3n^2 + n$ is divisible by both 2 and 3.

Tags: divisibility

I have to show that this is divisible by both 2 and 3. For the next, part I have to show that it's divisible by 6 which from what I understand is the same as showing it's divisible by 2 and 3.

Comment: It is equal to $2n^3+3n(n+1)$. The second term it multiple of $2$ because it is multiple of two consecutive integers $n$ and $n+1$, among which one must be even. It is also equal to $3n^3+n(2n^2+1)$. This is multiple of $3$ because in the second term either $n$ is multiple of $3$ or else $2n^2+1$ is multiple of $3$.

Comment: Just factor.  2n^3+3n+n=n (2n+1)(n+1).  One of n,n+1 must be even.  One of n,n+1 or 2n+1=3n-(n-1) must be divisible by 3.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3372218/

Comment: @lhf fyi: You don't need to explicitly link since the dupe link will already show in the "Linked" questions list (i.e.links are bidirectional).

Answer (score 2):

Factorising $2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1$ we get $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ As we know that sum of squares of first n natural numbers $$1^2+2^2+...+n^2 = {n(n+1)(2n+1)\over 6}$$ And since $$1^2+2^2+ ... + n^2$$ is an positive integer we can say that $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is divisible by 6 and hence $2n^3 + 3n^2 + 1$ is divisible by 2, 3 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\;2n^3 + 3n^2 + n = 2n(n+1)(n+2) -3n(n+1)\,$, then use that the product of $\,2\,$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $\,2\,$ and the product of $\,3\,$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $\,6\,$.

Answer (score 0):

By fermat theorem  $n^2=n (mod2)$ then 
$2n^3+3n^2+n = 2n+3n+n = 6n =0 (mod2)$
$2n^3+3n^2+n =2n+3n^2+3n $